# Return image binary data from api and display on html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm storing images at mongodb database. I want to display response i get from express api as image on client side. Image source looks like this

```
src="/image/data/5a44dde172aa021d107e7d33"
```

And i send back data like this. And when i write image url to browser it shows nothing.

```
var imgId = req.params.id;

imageModel.findById(imgId)
    .then((img) => {
        res.status(200).send(img.data);

    })
    .catch((exc) => {
        res.status(400).send();
    });
```

And i upload the file like this.

```
router.post("/", upload.any(), (req, res) => {


    if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            var file = req.files[i];

            var image = new imageModel({ data: file.buffer.toString(), name: file.fieldname, createdBy: req.user.id });
            image.save(function (err, img) {
                if (err)
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                else
                    res.status(200).send(response.create(img));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to set content-type

Comment: What is your `img.data` type? base64String? BinaryStirng?

Comment: When i send img.data directly and paste image url to browser it prompts download. But when i call toString() on img.data and set content-type to image/jpeg it displays an image but as a blank square only.

@hoangdv It's buffer type of mongoose. I think it stores data as binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solved this by changing

```
 file.buffer.toString()
```

to

```
 file.buffer.toString('binary')
```

on file upload code and

```
res.status(200).send(img.data)
```

to

```
 res.status(200).contentType("image/jpeg").send(new Buffer(img.data.toString(), 'binary'))
```

on get api method. It works as i expected, image can be displayed on page now.